# Issue creating alias with multiple arguments

Tags: bash, alias

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I open `~/.bashrc` and I have added some aliases, like   `alias c=clear` or `alias h=history`.  These aliases are working.

Problem is here:

```
alias ls=ls -lhF --time-style=long-iso --color=auto
```

When I type `ls` in the terminal, it shows me different output than when I just type `ls -lhF --time-style=long-iso --color=auto` manually.

---

tried that aswell, its still not working. Also when i type `alias ls` , i get that answer `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` 
so when i type manual `alias ls=ls -lhF --time-style=long-iso --color=auto` its looking complete diffrent

Comment: You need to learn about quoting in the shell: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html

Comment: *Where* in you `~/.bashrc` did you add the new alias? there is likely already an alias like `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` in the file, which will override yours if it occurs later

Comment: you were 100% right! in ~/.bashrc , there were already alias like ll=, la= l= and so on. Did not see it

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` as follows :

Change `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` to  `alias ls='ls -lhF --time-style=long-iso --color=auto'`

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls -lhF --time-style=long-iso --color=auto'
fi
```

single quote is missing, then run `exec $SHELL`.

---

Also you can put the new alias in your `~/.bash_aliases` , changes will be applied after sourcing your `~/.bashrc` through (present in ~/.bashrc) :

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

avoid adding duplicate aliases after the above lines allowing changes in `~/.bash_aliases` to take effects.

Comment: @boxerbobby see my edit, please.